# Python - do tuples copy the contents of lists or is it a reference?

Tags: python, list, performance, tuples

I want to return a list and a status code from a method in Python. I'm thinking of using a tuple because of its simplicity, but the issue is that the list may be huge, thus, copying it again into a tuple would result in some performance issues. Which is why I ask - does Python copy a list inside a tuple, or does Python take it as a reference?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```py
response = requests.get(self.base_url)
my_list = ast.literal_eval(response.text) # this just turns the string literal into a list
return (response, my_list)
```

Comment: Can you add some code to describe what you're trying to do? Are you asking about the performance of `tuple()` and how much data it copies?

Comment: In particular, there's a number of ways you can create a copy of a tuple off the top of my head -- there's `copy.copy()`, `copy.deepcopy()`, using `tuple()` and `list()`, etc., and I don't think the answer is the same for all three of these alone.

Comment: Added the relevant code snippet @BrokenBenchmark - I'm not trying to copy the list, on the contrary, I'm trying to avoid it. I say that the list may be huge because this is an API response from the database, that will potentially store quite a lot of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python takes it as a reference. You can verify this by creating a list, a tuple that contains the list, and then modifying the list and seeing whether the contents of the tuple change as well:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]
tup = (lst, 2)
lst[1] = 5
print(tup)
```

This outputs:

```py
([1, 5, 3], 2)
```

If `tup` made a copy of the list, the tuple's first element would be `[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be fine.

```
my_list = ast.literal_eval(response.text) 
x = (response, my_list)
```

will not copy the list, it will just be referenced in the tuple's second element.

You could try what happens to `my_list` if you do `x[1].append("foo")`...